# Multiple Marker Example using CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example/19420440#19420440)

Can you anyone help how to do Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker using CSV like the above which gets the Co-ordinates from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Multiple Marker</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        // change key of google map in key parameter
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var markers = []; // define global array in script tag so you can use it in whole page    
                var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(22.582365,79.848633);
                var mapProp = {
                        center:myCenter, 
                        zoom:6,
                        minZoom:6,          
                        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: true           
                    };
                //google map object       
                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gMap"),mapProp); 

                  //change event of input tag where type=file and  id=filename 
                  $("#filename").change(function(e) {

                     var ext = $("input#filename").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

                     if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) == -1) {
                            alert('Upload CSV');
                            return false;
                      }

                     if (e.target.files != undefined) {

                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function(e) {

                                      var csvval=e.target.result.split("\n");
                                      var csvvalue;                                          

                                      for(var i = 0;i < csvval.length;i++)
                                      {
                                              markers[i] = []; 
                                              csvvalue = csvval[i].split(",");
                                              markers[i][0] = csvvalue[0]; //id
                                              var lat = csvvalue[1]; //latitude
                                              var lng = csvvalue[2]; //longitude
                                              markers[i][1] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                                                   map: map                  
                                              });
                                       }

                             };
                             reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));
                       }

                     return false;

                    });
            });
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div style="width:1000px;height:600px;" id="gMap">
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="filename" name="filename"/>
        </body>
        </html>

 csv file will be like 

 1,22.582365,79.848633
 2,29.862893,77.8973
 3,23.01034,72.517397
 4,29.134187,79.125107

file must have csv extention , having no spaces
```

Comment: Could you please give me a clear picture fully using a sample CSV file and full code with all the HTML tags

Comment: check my answer again i added full page here only change google map key

Comment: Can it be done without this upload concept?? getting the values directly and plotting it??

Comment: yes i added no code for upload , directly extract points and plot them

Comment: No no without using file upload concept can u plot it using CSV??

Comment: i didn't upload file , but with out filereader it is not possible to extract points

Comment: Ok thank you... Actually I was browsing I found jquery-csv it could be implemented but I was wondering how it can be done... Is it possible??

Comment: no i don't think without reader it is possible, and may be jquery-csv is js which also use reader in script